# Reasons for using a self-implemented LinkedList instead of the Collections package?

Tags: java, collections

I have seen something very strange in this Android project on GitHub.

They are using recursive references instead of using buit-in data structures such as `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` for managing collections. What I mean is each object keeps a reference to the next object in the "collection" and implements methods like `size()` and `getNext()`;

See example here:
https://github.com/xxahtixx/aad2Project/blob/master/src/com/example/aad2project/object/Task.java

Why is this done?

Comment: Looks like your team is trying to reduce memory usage. Apart of that, I'm not aware what else could be.

Comment: You mean something like a [cons list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons)? These structures are more efficient for some things. Otherwise, this is a common pattern in design patterns such as [Chain of Responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `Task` is implemented as an unidirectional linked list.
You could use a generic list to accomplish something similar but that would bring all the code you don't need. e.g. `lastIndexOf(Object o)` in the case of an `ArrayList`.

Sometimes minimalist implementations are chosen for performance improvements. e.g. The list of Tasks in the example is likely to use less memory than an implementation using a generic list.